# how to improve Oracle select performance?

Tags: oracle11g

below query takes more than 1 minute, how to improve the performance. full scan is happening in both the tables. how to avoid?

**query plan:**

```
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 62  Bytes: 14,355  Cardinality: 45          
    3 HASH JOIN  Cost: 62  Bytes: 14,355  Cardinality: 45   
        1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE SYSADM.POSITIONS Cost: 9  Bytes: 520  Cardinality: 4  
        2 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE SYSADM.PORTCONSUMPTION Cost: 52  Bytes: 797,202  Cardinality: 4,218  



SELECT     
     a.Consumption    AS Consumption     ,
     a.Cost      AS Cost      ,
     a.CreatedBy     AS CreatedBy     ,
     a.CreatedDate    AS CreatedDate     ,
     a.UpdatedBy     AS UpdatedBy     ,
     a.UpdatedDate    AS UpdatedDate   

   FROM PortConsumption a   

   JOIN Positions b
   ON  a.PortRotationId = b.Id

   WHERE  b.VoyageId ='82A042031E1B4C38A9832A6678A695A4';
```

**Positions (**115970*** records)*

```
Id - Primary key (indexed)
VoyageId - indexed
```

**PortConsumption (**1291000*** records)*

```
Id - Primary key (indexed)
PortRotationId - indexed
```

after executing

dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ('SYSADM', 'POSITIONS');
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ('SYSADM', 'PORTCONSUMPTION');

full scan is not happening, but performance is still same , takes 50 secs.

Plan

```
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 20  Bytes: 16,536  Cardinality: 52                  
    6 NESTED LOOPS              
        4 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 20  Bytes: 16,536  Cardinality: 52        
            2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SYSADM.POSITIONS Cost: 5  Bytes: 520  Cardinality: 4    
                1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX SYSADM.INX_POSITIONS_VOYAGEID Cost: 3  Cardinality: 4  
            3 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX SYSADM.INX_PORTCONS_PORTROTID Cost: 2  Cardinality: 12     
        5 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SYSADM.PORTCONSUMPTION Cost: 4  Bytes: 2,256  Cardinality: 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to gather stats on the tables, because Oracle currently thinks POSITIONS has 4 rows not 115970, and that PORTCONSUMPTION has 4218 rows not 1.2 million, and hence that full scans of both is the best way to answer the query.

This code will gather stats on the 2 tables using default settings:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ('SYSADM', POSITIONS');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ('SYSADM', PORTCONSUMPTION ');
end;
```

See [DBMS_STATS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_stats.htm#autoId51) for more details on how to gather stats.

Comment: full scan not happening now after running stats, but still takes same time.

Comment: OK, well Oracle appears to think that the number of POSITIONS rows where VoyageId ='82A042031E1B4C38A9832A6678A695A4' is approximately 4.  Is that reasoable or way off?

Comment: yes you are right, positions has 5 records for VoyageId ='82A042031E1B4C38A9832A6678A695A4' PortConsumption table returns 45 records.

Comment: Stats seem reasonable then.  I don't know why it still takes 50 seconds to do that.

Comment: THANKS tony, after closing and reconnecting to db, it is fast now. takes in 50 millliseconds.